# Avoid timeouts on long angular $http queries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm facing an issue with an AngularJs app. My application needs to send a GET query to some python bottle server which will process a script for 3-4 minutes.

I'm actually using the $http.get method in angular but after a minute, I get a timeout if my python app hasn't answered yet. The python app continues processing but, because of the timeout, I won't be able to read the response in my promise function.

Is there any way to deal with this kind of queries avoiding both timeouts from browsers and angular app?

Comment: Send progress headers or something similar to let your app know your server is still there.

Comment: How can I do it? Like yield something with my python while my processing is running?

Comment: Depending on what tooling you're using (you haven't specified in your question), the keywords you're looking for are probably _stream progress_ or _yield progress_, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: I found that it was nGinx that was timing my queries out after trying every solution I could in my code... ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom timeout for your http request in the second parameter of `http.get()` method:

```
$http.get('request-path', {timeout: 300000});
```

This will set timeout to 300 seconds = 5 minutes.

Comment: While setting a long timeout works, it has the dreadful downside that when something actually _does_ go wrong and your server goes offline or otherwise unavailable, the user has to wait for five minutes to find out.